# argv[0] change blocking or logging by linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Is it possible to block in linux the possibility to overwrite the argv[0] variable, e.g. strcpy(argv[0], "test", strlen(argv[0]))? I want to block or at least to log this changes.

P.S. I'm eager to change the kernel, just help me to find in what call or function in kernel source I can "catch" this change. I've noticed while argv[0] changes, the content of /proc/_pid_cmdline also changes, I've tried to put a simple logging into proc_pid_cmdline() in fs/proc/base.c but it didn't work just how I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I may ask, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Presumably because of malware that changes its command line so it shows up as something harmless in `ps` output. Of course there are many better ways for malware to disguise itself, so this seems like a waste of effort...

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the solution would be to make the memory page containing the arguments read-only, which would cause a memory access violation when attempting to change the contents. By modifying the C runtime stub or Linux kernel, one could then catch that and decide what to do afterwards.

Comment: Be aware that anything done in the context of the process itself (such as C startup code) is generally possible to counteract - there's no requirement that a program be written in C, or that a C program not play tricks on its own compiler/linker provided stubs and structures.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lot easier/better to just "fix" the kernel not to expose `argv` via `/proc/$pid/cmdline`; arguably, this is actually a dangerous security leak, exposing private memory belonging to the process. For instance, this is a stupid example, but a conforming program could store passwords, encryption keys, etc. in the space previously occupied by its argument string after it's done using the arguments.

If you really do want to allow but log changes to `cmdline`, it's going to be a lot harder. You would have to arrange for the data to be in an initially-read-only page, and trap writes to it, allowing the write but logging the change when a write attempt occurs. This would be really fragile and hard to maintain, I think.

Comment: NO! Even remotely suggesting that the command line paramaters should be private is extremely dangerous thinking, as it leads to a temptation to overlook other ways in which they easily leak, such as shell history, log files, etc.  And a program which abuses that memory to store other sensitive information is a program written by a dangerously incompetent author who can be expected to have made numerous other mistakes.

Comment: I didn't say the command line should be private. I said memory which belongs to the application, which happened to initially contain the command line, should be private. There's a big difference in exposing the initial command line with which an application was executed, and dynamically exposing the current contents of part of an application's private address space.

Comment: The case of a programmer overwriting explicitly non-private information with private information is absurd, because it requires the programmer to go out of their way to demonstrate stunning incompetence in security thinking.  So you'll have to come up with a much better argument than protecting gross incompetents from themselves for why the kernel should hide that information.

Comment: Here's a thought. Suppose the program has stored private information into its environment for sharing with a child process. This is supposed to be secure. Now, an otherwise-unexploitable vuln happens to allow an attacker to overwrite the null termination at the end of `argv[argc-1]` (and possibly an arbitrary number of bytes immediately after it). Now, `argv[argc-1]` is no longer null-terminated, and the kernel happily keeps reading after it (into the environment) and exposes the environment via `cmdline` in `/proc`. Happy? :-)

Comment: Actually, if the application filled all the way from the end of `argv[argc-1]` to `0xbfffffff` with non-null bytes, I wonder if this would result in a vulnerability that would expose the beginning of kernel address space (up to the first 0 byte) to userspace via `cmdline`...

Comment: @R - no, unless the kernel was written by a gross incompetent who thought it should trust things userspace handed it.  A kernel which lets you expose its private address space by handing it an unterminated terminated string is extremely broken - or a library for use in a cooperative environment rather than a true kernel for a multiuser one.

Comment: @netcoder - if you are aware of actual vulnerabilities, please post them to the kernel list.  What we are looking at there is more vague thinking that relies on stacking multiple beginner-level mistakes to add up to an exploit.

Comment: The kind of information-exposing that `cmdline` does *might not* be exploitable, or might only be exploitable if the application does stupid (albeit legal) things, but it's still a fundamentally insecure design for the kernel to be exposing part of the process's address space in `/proc`.

Comment: R. - perhaps you should try that argument on LKML, but I doubt it will go far, as you are basically arguing that something nobody thinks of as private should be private to protect against people who lack the skills for handling private information.

Comment: No, I'm arguing that you shouldn't have dangerous features that could easily turn into exploits, especially when the only practical use of this "feature" is applications misrepresenting themselves in ps output.

Comment: For what it's worth, the expose-the-environment issue **does** exist: if you can smash the end of `argv`, the environment gets exposed through `cmdline`. However, the expose-kernel-memory issue does not exist. If the kernel reads all the way to 0xc0000000 without hitting a null byte, then `cmdline` reads completely empty.